# postgres update NEW variable before INSERT in a TRIGGER

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I've two tables `accounts` and `projects`:

```
create table accounts (
  id          bigserial primary key,
  slug        text unique
);


create table projects (
  id          bigserial primary key,
  account_id  bigint not null references accounts (id),
  name        text
);
```

I want to be able to insert a new row into `projects` by specifying only `account.slug` (not `account.id`). What I'm trying to achieve is something like:

```
INSERT into projects (account_slug, name) values ('account_slug', 'project_name');
```

I thought about using a trigger (unfortunately it doesn't work):

```
create or replace function trigger_projects_insert() returns trigger as $$
begin
  if TG_OP = 'INSERT' AND NEW.account_slug then

    select id as account_id
      from accounts as account
      where account.slug = NEW.account_slug;

    NEW.account_id = account_id;

    -- we should also remove NEW.account_slug but don't know how

  end if;
  return NEW;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger trigger_projects_insert before insert on projects
  for each row execute procedure trigger_projects_insert();
```

What is the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Is a trigger a good idea?
Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH newacc AS (
   INSERT INTO accounts (slug)
      VALUES ('account_slug')
      RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO projects (account_id, name)
   SELECT id, 'project_name'
      FROM newacct;
```

If you are limited in the SQL you can use, another idea might be to define a view over both tables and create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the view that performs the two `INSERT`s on the underlying tables. Then an `INSERT` statement like the one in your question would work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using https://postgrest.com/en/v0.4/, don't know if you're familiar with it, your solution even if correct, won't really work using postgrest, that's why i would like to use a trigger.

Comment: I'd say that you should use something different if it keeps you from using the database properly, but it might not b your choice. I'll add a different idea, maybe that will help.